# Cookie on an intranet domain

Tags: http, cookies

I have a dev server in our office that is behind the firewall.  The hostname is franklin.  We name all our servers after scientists or inventors.

When I set an HTTP cookie:

```
 Set-Cookie: user=kenny; expires=1245424860.11; Path=/; domain=franklin
```

The cookie doesn't set.  I have tried the following with no luck.

```
.franklin
.franklin.local
franklin.local
.franklin.localdomain
franklin.localdomain
```

Do I have to set the hostname to something different or can I set this cookie through some magic I don't know already?

Comment: oddly enough I dropped the domain=franklin and it set the cookie.  Using firefox's web developer tool bar it says the domain is franklin.  Not sure what was going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109) says:

> To prevent possible security or privacy violations, a user agent
> **rejects** a cookie (shall not store its information) if any of the
> following is true:

> - The value for the Domain attribute contains no embedded dots or
>   does not start with a dot.
> - The value for the request-host does not domain-match the Domain
>   attribute.

And also:

> Domain Defaults to the request-host.

If your host is `franklin`:

- Cookies with `domain=.franklin` will be rejected, because it has no embedded dot.
- Cookies with `domain=.franklin.local` will be rejected, because it does not match the actual host name of your server.

The solution is to rename your hostname to `franklin.local` or `franklin.<tld>` and set the `domain` attribute of the cookie accordingly (`domain=.franklin.<tld>`). Alternatively (as you found out), do not specify the `domain`, and let the user agent fallback to the request host.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the cookie from the right domain? You should access the website over http://franklin/ otherwise it wouldn't work (see: same origin policy).