# A cookie without a domain?

Tags: cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

Is it possible to set a cookie without a domain?

This will mean all domains will have access to it.

Comment: What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, that is not possible. If a cookie doesn't declare a domain, [the browser will assume the domain of the object requested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_path).

What you're asking for is generally considered a security, or at least privacy, risk. It's possible to configure browsers to allow access to cookies from other than the domain that they were created, but browsers aren't commonly configured that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Follow up question, is possible to set cookie on domain but specify that another domain has access to it?

Comment: @jamjam, no, it isn't. The normal way of dealing with this restriction is to place all applications that need access to the same cookie in the same domain.

Comment: not all browsers will assume domain if a cookie doesn't declare a domain.

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019876/cookie-on-an-intranet-domain).. FireFox 13 can also control whether domain is assumed when cookie doesn't declare one.

Comment: I don't see where the question you reference makes that point, @Frank. I'd be interested in a reference for the Firefox 13 setting.

Comment: [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)The host or domain for which the cookie is set. presence of a leading dot indicates a domain cookie; otherwise, the cookie is treated as a non-domain cookie. See RFC2109 for details. The host string will be normalized to ASCII or ACE; any trailing dot will be stripped. To be a domain cookie, the host must have at least two subdomain parts (e.g. '.foo.com', not '.com'), otherwise an exception will be thrown. An empty string is acceptable (e.g. file:// URI's).

Comment: Yes, that *is* a quote from RFC2109, @Frank, and that RFC is discussed in the article I link to. How does that quote support your point?

Comment: Plenty of homebrew scripts [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=cookies&submit=) that can override the default. You can use a fireFox add-on called [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to run them!

Answer (score 6):

RFC 2109 tells this parameter is optional. But depending on the browser, behavior may be different.