# Graphql Set-Cookie being sent but not being set

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, apollo-server, graphql-js

After experimenting with different configurations found on questions similar to this, none of them seem to work. Set-Cookie is being sent by express, however the browser isn't setting it in Application -> Cookies

This question is for when I am running frontend on `localhost:7000` and backend on `localhost:4000`

Frontend Technologies: vite, react, @tanstack/react-query, graphql-request (fetcher), @graphql-codegen, @graphql-codegen/typescript-react-query (Using this to generate react-query hooks for graphql)

Backend Technologies: @apollo/server, type-graphql, express, express-sessions

Repo for reproducing: https://github.com/Waqas-Abbasi/cookies-not-set-repro

Backend Server:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'dotenv/config';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import http from 'http';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import cors, { CorsRequest } from 'cors';
import session from 'express-session';
import buildSchemaFacade from './graphql/buildSchemaFacade';
import { redisStore } from './api/redis';

const SEVEN_DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

const {
    NODE_ENV,
    PORT = 4000,
    SESSION_LIFETIME = SEVEN_DAYS,
    SESSION_SECRET
} = process.env;

async function bootstrap() {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient();

    const app = express();
    const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

    const schema = await buildSchemaFacade();

    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer })]
    });

    await server.start();

    app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json());

    app.use(
        '/graphql',
        cors<CorsRequest>({
            origin: 'http://localhost:7000',
            credentials: true
        })
    );

    app.use(
        '/graphql',
        session({
            proxy: true,
            name: 'sessionID',
            cookie: {
                maxAge: SESSION_LIFETIME as number,
                sameSite: 'lax',
                secure: NODE_ENV === 'production',
                httpOnly: true
            },
            resave: false,
            secret: SESSION_SECRET as string,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            store: redisStore
        })
    );

    app.use(
        '/graphql',
        expressMiddleware(server, {
            context: async ({ req, res }) => ({ prisma, req, res })
        })
    );

    await new Promise<void>((resolve) =>
        httpServer.listen({ port: PORT || 4000 }, resolve)
    );

    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000/graphql`);
}

bootstrap();
```

Frontend:

GraphQL Client:

```
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request';

export const graphqlClient = new GraphQLClient(import.meta.env.VITE_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT as string, {
    headers: {
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors',
    },
});
```

Login.tsx:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useLoginUserMutation } from '@platform/graphql/__generated__/graphql';
import { graphqlClient } from '@platform/graphql/graphqlClient';

export default function Login() {
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const { mutate } = useLoginUserMutation(graphqlClient);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const email = (event.target as HTMLFormElement).email.value;
        const password = (event.target as HTMLFormElement).password.value;

        mutate(
            { email, password },
            {
                onSuccess: (data) => {
                    // navigate('/dashboard/orders');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                onError: (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    setError('Something went wrong with logging in');
                },
            }
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex h-screen items-center justify-center bg-slate-100">
            <div className="w-[300px] space-y-4  bg-white p-5">
                <h1 className="text-xl font-bold">Login</h1>
                <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="flex flex-col space-y-4 text-lg">
                    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex flex-col space-y-2">
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" />
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" className="w-fit  bg-black p-2 px-4 text-white">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </form>
                {error && <div className="text-red-500">{error}</div>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Response when pressing Login Button:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:

I also tried solution:

https://community.apollographql.com/t/cookie-not-shown-stored-in-the-browser/1901/8

Setting cookie’s secure field to be `true` and setting sameSite to `none`, and also passing `x-forwarded-proto` with value `https` in the graphQL client.

Still it does not work. On a side note, it is working as expected on Insomnia, just not on any browsers

EDIT 2:
I've also tried replacing graphql-request with urql and apollo client, still the same issue. This leads me to think this might be a backend issue with how express session is initialised, and for some reason the browser does not like the `Set-Cookie` that is sent from the backend

EDIT 3:

`./api/redis`:

```js
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import session from 'express-session';
import RedisClient from 'ioredis';

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = new RedisClient();

export const redisStore = new RedisStore({ client: redisClient });

export default redisClient;
```

Edit 4:

Repo for reproducing: https://github.com/Waqas-Abbasi/cookies-not-set-repro

Comment: Can you show what's happening inside `./api/redis`?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Updated and added it, but out of curiosity not sure why that would be important to this question? Since the session cookie is indeed being sent, and on Insomnia it is working as expected. My intuition is that the browser doesn't like the `Set-Cookie` being sent by the backend

Comment: I agree with you. I mostly was curious so I could try to reproduce this in sandbox and learn from it. I've used most of these libraries and concepts except GraphQL and just wanted to make sure no environment-based conditionals were happening here. If I find something I'll update with an answer.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu I've added a minimal repo link, you can try it out there, Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I reproduced the issue and mistakenly thought I saw cookies being set after an adjustment. Very strange - I'm still checking and will re-revise the answer if I find it.

Comment: I found the issue and am now able to pass the generated session cookie to the client and see it on both :7000 and :4000 - updating my answer now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the incorrect answer is marked as resolved - `credentials` and `mode` - (along with many other options such as `body`, `signal`, `cache` etc exist on the `headers` object. Simply verify by inspecting the type definitions. Adding screenshots to my answer to share.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Hmm, that answer did actually do the trick for me, so once I press login, it sets the cookie ^^ I looked into a bit and it seems he is right that those values don't exist on the header but on the request object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GraphQL client definition, replace

```
headers: {
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'cors',
}
```

with

```
credentials: 'include',
mode: 'cors'
```

because these are not headers, they are parameters of the request.

Without the [`credentials: 'include'` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters) in the request, the `fetch` method will neither send nor receive any [*cross-origin*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#same-origin) cookies, where a difference in the port (`localhost:7000` vs. `localhost:4000`) already makes a request cross-origin. That's why I believe this to be the solution.

Wesley LeMahieu's answer handles the question when a cookie counts as [*same-site*](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis.html#same-site-requests), where the port does not matter when [obtaining a site](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#obtain-a-site). `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are not same-site.

Cookies with `SameSite: Lax` are sent or received by a `fetch` request only if this is same-site. In the question, the `fetch` request is same-site, but cross-origin, and therefore requires the `credentials: 'include'` option.

Comment: While this technically works on the type definition, it's not any reason for the backend Apollo GraphQL server to not pass the express session cookie to the frontend. I just tested with and without your change - in both situations my Express sessionID propagates from backend to frontend without issue. --- I will provide a working codesandbox shortly so future readers don't make assumptions about provided solutions.

Comment: I have added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Heiko - great writeup and information. What's strange is the OP mentions they use `npm run dev` for frontend (which opens 127.0.0.1:7000) and `npm run start` for backend (which opens localhost:4000/graphql) - two separate domains. This did not work for me. When I manually switched my client to `localhost:7000` I saw cookies propagating from server to client - without making your change --- keeping `credentials = 'include'` inside the `headers:{}` object. I then tested and moved them outside the object, reset all cookies and retried --- I still get cookies propagating. Just an FYI.

Comment: Just for clarification, I was using `localhost:7000` as mentioned in the question :) and it was still not working with the repro I linked. I think the main difference here was that in your solution, you set `saveUninitialized` to be `true` and I'm not sure why that works even though the request is being made without proper request parameters (`credientials`)

Comment: I was wrong regarding the placement of these options after a discussion with the OP. There is a difference in our environments where the suggested fix actually break it for me, but that's besides the point --- I would give Heiko an upvote (sorry for the downvote) if he edited the response in some fashion as this is a correct answer.

Comment: I made a minor edit.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, it did not work for me locally. The solution for me to ensure safe passage of `sessionID` between `GraphQL` and the client was this client-side connector:

```
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request';

export const graphqlClient = new GraphQLClient('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});
```

I'm using `http://localhost:7000` and `http://localhost:4000/graphql`, clearing cookies on both frontend and backend browser tabs, force-refreshing :4000 to generate session, then force-refreshing :7000 to receive the `sessionID` from `GraphQL`.

****Please keep in mind:**

There are other reasons why the `Express` session would not be passed on from `GraphQL` to the client and subsequently not stored in browser cookie storage.

In order for the `Express` `sessionID` to propagate from the backend to the frontend, you need to be using the **same host**. So both sides need to run on `localhost`, or both on `127.0.0.1`.

**These work:**

```
http://localhost:4000/graphql
http://localhost:7000/

http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
http://127.0.0.1:7000/
```

**These do not work:**

```
http://localhost:4000/graphql
http://127.0.0.1:7000/

http://127.0.0.1:4000/graphql
http://localhost:7000/
```

Comment: The code piece you're referring to is already part of the express initialisation (The cors middleware takes care of this). I tried the guide you are referring to (you can refer to my first Edit part of the post), even then it doesn't work unfortunately. Do also note that I am not using the Apollo Playground for my testing rather my frontend, but since apollo playground is also run on the browser, the same issue persists

Comment: Just a note, that also confused me a lot as well, hence why I initially set the `mode` and `credentials` inside `headers`! The  type you are showing in the screenshot is the `RequestInit`  rather than the `Headers`. The type of headers property is `HeadersInit`.  It's just that when you observe the type definitions through the editor, it doesn't show you the the type of the header but it just redirects you to `RequestInit` first, and from there you can click `HeadersInit` to see the actual type. This is in reference to when you inspect `MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit['headers']>;`

Comment: It's not confusing with VSCode type definition inspection. It never gets confused and takes 3 seconds to delve into nested type definitions --- Start by right-clicking `GraphQLClient` in your `graphqlClient.ts` - It accepts 2 parameters, right? `url` string and `options` `PatchedRequestInit` which clearly only contains 3 possible properties. `headers`, `requestMiddleware`, `responseMiddleware`. Specifically right-click the `'headers'` string inside `MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit[` - this clearly indicates `body`, `cache`, `credentials`, `mode`, etc.

Comment: Yes, but there's one more step involved, When you click on `MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit['headers']>` - it doesn't take you to the type definition of headers, rather it takes you to the type definition of `RequestInit`, from there you can see the typeDefinition of `headers`. Alternatively, if you hover over `MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit['headers']>`, vscode will show you the actual type definition `HeadersInit | undefined`. 

Notice that you when actually click on the `headers`, Vscode redirects you to the `headers` property of `RequestInit`

Comment: If you hover over `MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit['headers']>`, what does VScode show you as the type? For me it shows `HeadersInit | undefined`

Now if you click on the type, notice you are redirected to `RequestInit` rather than `HeadersInit`

Comment: Here it is.`GraphQLClient` class takes a `url` `string` and an `options` `PatchedRequestInit`. And `options` is then of type `PatchedRequestInit`. We see this is an `intersection type`! It is BOTH `Omit<Dom.RequestInit, 'headers'>` AND `{ headers?: MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit['headers']>; ... }` - This proves that `credentials` and `mode` can be set both INSIDE `headers`, as you originally had it, but also as a sibling. --- This is what it is and explains why your code works for me. --- I suspect you actually were using 127.0.0.7000 and localhost:4000 together. That's how your app boots. :)

Comment: Yes it is indeed an intersection, but again VSCode is not showing you the correct type here when you click inside `MaybeFunction<Dom.RequestInit['headers']>;`  - You can hover over the `headers` property in this type, and VSCode will show you the type `HeadersInit` and `HeadersInit` does not `credentials` and `mode` inside it. When you click the `headers` property, VScode simply redirects you to `Dom.RequestInit` and places the cursor on `headers`, but it doesn't direct you to the actual type of `headers`

Comment: You're 100% incorrect. --- VSCode is not confused on what the type definition is. --- ALSO, I just verified by checking the actual `Request Headers` when submitting the login form to the backend. With your ORIGINAL CODE, I see `credentials: include` and `mode: cors` included! --- Now, I remove them from `headers:` and try the "Accepted Solution", now the `credentials: include` is MISSING, and the `mode: cors` is MISSING. --- You know how to read headers, explain that? You're confused and mistaken. I'm glad because I now realize why many wrong answers get marked as solutions here.

Comment: Because `credentials` and `mode` are not headers, why would/should they be inside the headers?  You can add anything inside of `headers` object and it will show up in the request headers, hence why in my original question, adding them as headers, actually shows them as headers in the request, but since they are not actually headers, my original repro doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251808/discussion-between-learning-developer-9-and-wesley-lemahieu).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not totally certain, but a few things :

First, the set-cookie doesn't show a domain in your cookie which [should fall back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019876/cookie-on-an-intranet-domain) to the request host, however this might depend on your browser

Second, you set a path to "/" according to [the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) this will not match with your "/graphql" path.

Finally, your screens look like Firefox, but you say you search your cookies in "Application -> Cookies" and in modern Firefox it should be in "Storage -> Cookies"

Comment: Thanks for response. The domain is localhost as you can see from the last screenshot (fallbacks to the host url correctly on all browsers). The Path `/` I believe applies to all routes, since according to MDN Docs, Path=/docs matches with the request paths /docs, /docs/, /docs/Web/, and /docs/Web/HTTP will all match. I've also verified that by changing the path to `/graphql` there is no effect. Screenshots were of Chrome ^^, but I've verified the same issue exists on all browsers and I've inspected the cookie storage for every browser